# Querying data from a child table in .Net Mobile service

Tags: sql, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have two simple models in .net backend based Azure Mobile Service Project, as shown below & I am not able to query the child table (querying parent table, UserItem, works just fine)

(The Id is nvarchar(128) & is autogenerated as newId by DB)

```
public class AnswerItem: EntityData 
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public UserItem By { get; set; }
    public QuestionItem ForQuestion { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

& a child to this UserItem Table as shown below

```
public class QuestionItem: EntityData
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnswered { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfAnswers {get; set;}
    public UserItem By { get; set; }
    public string ById { get; set; }
    public string AtLocation { get; set; }
}
```

As you notice, the QuestionItem has a FK relationship to UserItem table on ById field (Referencing Id field in UserItem Table)

The issue is I am getting a Bad Request error when I try to query the data from child table 
Following are some queries that I tried

```
private IMobileServiceTable<QuestionItem> questionTable =        App.MobileService.GetTable<QuestionItem>();

questions = await questionTable.Where(x=>x.IsAnswered==true).ToCollectionAsync(); (Does not Work)

questions = await questionTable.Where(x=>x.ById="UserIdGoesHere").ToCollectionAsync(); (Does Not Work) 

questions = await questionTable.Where(x=>x.Content.StartsWith("q")).ToCollectionAsync(); (This Works) 

questions = await questionTable.ToCollectionAsync(); (This Works as well)
```

If I fire a TSQL query in Sql Server Object explorer they all return correct values. 
I am at my wits end on what could be wrong with my approach.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks 
Supreet

Comment: What are the errors you're getting for the queries that don't work?

Comment: I get a Bad Request response. Downloading additional debug symbols & trying to get into the Query() method also does not reveal anything specific.

Comment: Investigating further the Request it was generating was like this 
    
    192.168.2.4:50002/tables/QuestionItem?$filter=(byid eq 'myUniqueGuId') 

analyzing fiddler output shows this error

     "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'byid' on type 'x2Service.DataObjects.QuestionItem'" 

Off course there is no fields in the table by the name of 'byid' the one I have is called 'ById' Its the JsonProperty adorner that changed it 

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "byid")] In my client class. 
Removed the Json Property & it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating further the Request it was generating was like this

```
192.168.2.4:50002/tables/QuestionItem?$filter=(byid eq 'myUniqueGuId')
```

analyzing fiddler output shows this error

"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'byid' on type 'x2Service.DataObjects.QuestionItem'"

Off course there is no fields in the table by the name of 'byid' the one I have is called 'ById' Its the JsonProperty adorner that changed it [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "byid")] In my client class.

Removed the Json Property & it worked just fine